# Upper limit proof that I don't understand

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I don't understand the part where they mention $w \in$ lim $A_n$ I don't understand the part of the fact that w is in finitely many of the $A_n$.

I understand that upper limit is union of intersection, so if $w \in$ lim $A_n$ then 
it must have a k such that it will inside $A_k,A_{k+1},A_{k+2},....$ but how come it is not in infinitely many because as we move towards union of the intersection of the next sequence that is of $A_{k + 1} \cup A_{k + 2} \cup A_{k + 3},...$, then it will be inside those aswell. can someone clarify more on this part.
[image]

Comment: all but finitely many means it is infinitely many. It means that it is one of those infinite intersections. The finite amount it is not in are the sets before that

Comment: Oh okay I see now that would make much more sense I had that in my head but I was wondering if that is correct. Thank you Kamster....

Comment: No problem I had same problem when first learning that stuff to it takes time to wrap head around. But is super useful

Comment: yeah exactly but as you get to know the knowledge it is super useful !

Comment: Just wondering again I thought for the $\phi$ in this case how come is it not in infinitely many it will be in all sets even the ones before it. Also if you want to add it as an answer I will accept it if you want.

Comment: I guess I dont really understand your question? also is $\phi$ supposed to represent the null set in your question

Comment: Yes it represent the null set, since first in their assumption if lim $A_n$ = $\phi$.

Comment: Yes it represent the null set, since first in their assumption if $A_n$ = $\phi$ the it must be in all and hence it is in infinitely many not finitely many I don’t understand this part..

Comment: Well doesn't it say that it means it is not in all the set that contains "all but finitely many" has no elements (ie empty) thus it equals the null set

Comment: Yes I don't understand that part being in infinitely many I guess it satisfies it vacuously right? because being in infinitely many means $w \in \forall$ $\cap A_k$ is false, however I don't understand how come it must be then in finitely many ?

Comment: well if you have $\cup\cap A_k=\emptyset$ then this is only possible if every $\cap A_k$ must equal $\emptyset$ since $B\cup A=\emptyset$ is true only when $A=B=\emptyset$

Comment: Yes yes, I understood it now thanks kamster. If you want to add it as answer I will accept your answer.

Comment: It's fine I don't really care about that anymore as long as you understand now

Comment: Yes, it is perfectly clear now thanks alot !